# SSLConnectionSocketFactory thread blocked indefinately during GET

Tags: java, multithreading

Sometimes my thread gets blocked during handshake..I am using http-client 4.4.1. Below is my code for GET. How do I set timeout for this?

```
public HttpResponseBean get(String url, Map<String, String> headers) throws Exception {
    logger.debug("Sending get request...");

    HttpClient httpClient = null;
    try {
        int timeout = 30 * 1000; // 30 seconds
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(timeout)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout)
                .setSocketTimeout(timeout).build();
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
        HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        if (headers != null) {
            for (Entry<String, String> entry: headers.entrySet()) {
                httpGetRequest.addHeader(new BasicHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
            }
        }

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
        HttpResponseBean hrb = new HttpResponseBean(response);
        logger.debug("Get response: Response: " + hrb.toString());
        return hrb;
    } finally {
        closeConnection(httpClient);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a connection timeout

Comment: Thats already present!

Comment: Have you tested your code with different servers? Sometimes it is a server problem not a client problem.